# How can I view/set build option in file properties

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I feel like asking a dumb question, but I just do not see the options I need in Visual Studio 2010 File Properties. The only options I see are: File Name, and Full Path. What I need to set is: Build Action, and Copy To Output Directory.

Question update:

I just found out that File Properties shows the Advanced options for files in class libraries, but not for files from the actual web site. But how do I set the mentioned options to the resource file App_GlobalResources/Contact.resx , which by default does not appear in the published version of the web project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ASP.NET Precompilation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx)

**Resources (.resx) files:**

> For .resx files in the App_GlobalResources folders, generates an
>   assembly or assemblies and a culture structure. For .resx files in the
>   App_LocalResources folders, copies files as is to the
>   App_LocalResources folder of the output location.

**Assemblies are put in the Bin folder**

Comment: Thanks for your info, but precompilation is about making the site load faster. I need to be able to edit the resource file at run time. I am not sure this will solve my problem, will look at the bin filder though.

Comment: You cannot change the resources files in the Global Resource folder at run-time.  You can change resources in the Local Resource folder at run-time if updateable is checked.

Comment: If that is true, then it makes sense that the global resx is not present in the output. I'll be looking into using Local resx, thanks.